# Sobol variance based decomposition

Tags: monte-carlo, normality-assumption, uniform-distribution, sensitivity-analysis

I have 6 input variables, each of which is normally distributed. Can I use [Sobol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobol_sequence) variance-based sensitivity analysis? I have read some articles where they said that input variables must have uniform distributions. Is that correct?

Comment: I see nothing off topic about asking if variance based sensitivity analyses can be used with normally distributed data.

Answer (score 1):

That is not correct.

Variance-based sensitivity indices **can work** for data distributed according to **any probability distribution** as long as you know what they are. And, of course, normally distributed ones.

You can find more about this, for example, in [this article](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00743964/document).

You want to use R for computation, I recommend you the [sensitivity package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sensitivity/index.html).

PS: I am very interested to know in which articles you have seen that input variables must have uniform distributions

Comment: As you seem very interesting in investigating sobol indices, I would like to ask you a little question : Can sobol indices be applied to discrete random varibales ?  Thank you in advance .

Comment: It can be applied to discrete **input** random variables without any change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply ! I would like to know if you have any references for this idea ( examples where sobol indices are applied to  discrete input variables) ?  Thank you again :)

Comment: here a paper where it is stated that we can use Sobol with discrete inputs (table 1): http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/psp4.6/pdf And here a paper in which it is actually done on a small example (section 5): http://www.informs-sim.org/wsc97papers/0261.PDF

Comment: OH HH Thank you again,  why not adding your answer on [my question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190843/sobol-indices-for-discrete-variables) so I can marked it as an answered question.